# Announce rake stdout with cucumber and aruba

Tags: cucumber, rake, rake-task, aruba

How to tell cucumber/aruba to display the stdout of a rake command. The following code doesn't work for me

```
@announce
Scenario: test rake task
 When I run 'rake -verion'
 Then the output should contain "0.9.2.2"
```

Even with the @announce tag, the stdout of the command "rake -version" is not outputted.

Answer (score 0):

The rake command has a typo, [the aruba call with a quoted command is deprecated in favor of backticks](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/blob/master/lib/aruba/cucumber.rb), and you are missing a Given clause (although it does work without it):

```
Scenario: test rake task
 When I run `rake --version`
 Then the output should contain "0.9.2.2"
```